# How to use Filter() on multiple level object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

I was wondering how to use filter() on an array of objects like this one:

```
const tattoos = [
  {
    head: [
      {
        name: "1 - Crâne de pirate (H/F)",
        gender: "HF",
        price: "450",

      },
      {
        name: "2 - Surf LS (H/F)",
        gender: "HF",
        price: "250",
      },
      {
        // etc...
      },
    ],
    torso: [
      {
        name: "1 - Crâne de pirate (H/F)",
        gender: "HF",
        price: "450",

      },
      {
        name: "2 - Surf LS (H/F)",
        gender: "HF",
        price: "250",
      },
      {
        // etc...
      },
    ],
```

I want to use it in this React Component:

```
// SIMPLE VERSION FOR EASIER UNDERSTANDING

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const tattoos = [{...}]

export default function Searchbar() {
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
  const [bodypart, setBodypart] = useState("all");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setBodypart(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bodypart === "all") {
      setFiltered(tattoos);
      return;
    }

    const filtered = tattoos.filter( // This is where I'm stuck )
    setFiltered(filtered);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Bodypart:
          </label>
          <select onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="head">Head</option>
            <option value="torso">Torso</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expected behavior:

- Click on an option
- Store the value in "bodypart" state
- Use filter() on the main array and filter using "bodypart" state

I already tried:

```js
const filtered = tattoos.filter(e => e === bodypart)
const filtered = tattoos.filter(e => e.includes(bodypart))
const filtered = tattoos.filter(e => e.some(bodypart))
const filtered = tattoos.filter(e => Objects.keys(e).includes(bodypart))
```

But I always ended with an empty array or an error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tattoos` array seems to consist of just 1 object, or at least you don't show any more than 1 item. If that is indeed all it contains, then you can take `tattoos[0]` and then access the needed property using `[bodypart]`.

```js
const tattoos = [
  {
    head: [
      { name: "1 - Crâne de pirate (H/F)", gender: "HF", price: "450" },
      { name: "2 - Surf LS (H/F)", gender: "HF", price: "250" },
    ],
    torso: [
      { name: "1 - Crâne de pirate (H/F)", gender: "HF", price: "450" },
      { name: "2 - Surf LS (H/F)", gender: "HF", price: "250" },
    ],
  }
];

const bodypart = "torso";
const filtered = tattoos[0][bodypart];
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Oh god  silly me, it was so simple... thanks a lot !